# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, Network is unreachable message when I run #sudo apt-get update

Tags: networking

I am not able to access internet from command prompt. Though I can access it from my browser.In network proxy I have enabled automatic mode and put proxy address and it works fine from browser. on browser when ever I have to browse some page I need to give username/password info.

Problem :

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                    
    Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable
```

I did below steps to solve this issue:

1. set http_proxy variable from command prompt.
2. verified /etc/apt/sources.list with below

   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
3. /etc/netplan/*yaml looks fine.

Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
      eno1:
          addresses: [10.120.26.158/24]
          gateway4: 10.120.26.1
          dhcp4: true
          optional: true
          nameservers:
              addresses: [10.120.25.152, 10.120.81.25, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

I am not sure what I am missing.

**Adding some new information**

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5123ms

$ ip addr show

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:d9:d2:04:54:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.120.26.158/24 brd 10.120.26.255 scope global noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::cad9:d2ff:fe04:547e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$ ip route
default via 10.120.26.1 dev eno1 proto static metric 20100 
10.120.26.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 10.120.26.158 metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eno1 scope link metric 1000
```

I have set proxy for only http and not for https and ftp.

Comment: `apt-get update` uses ipv6, but your network configuration is only ipv4... can you add the output of `ip addr show` to your question?

Comment: Can you please post your routing table (ip route) and a test ping to, say, 8.8.8.8 (Google's DNS server)? Does your net admin require a proxy for the HTTP/HTTPS traffic?

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain why apt doesn't use the environment variables, but I hit this problem myself on a network where I had to use a proxy.

What you need to do it tell apt that you want to use a proxy.  This can be solved by adding a snippet file in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/

The filename is up to you.
The content of this file must be:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxy-you-need-to-use:8080/";
```

Obviously, you set between the double quotes what you have set in your environment variable.

After that apt should work just fine.

For a one-liner, this should work:

```
echo 'Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxy-you-need-to-use:8080/";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10-proxy-you-need-to-use
```

Again, obviously, you need to adapt the http://  part to the actual proxy.

Most CLI command are proxy-aware, but not all and it is no requirement as far as I know.

Comment: after the above command==$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                            
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                
Ign:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease               
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 10.120.80.79 80]
--Reading package lists... Done                              
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release' no longer has a Release file.

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02proxy`, use the syntax:

```
Acquire::http { Proxy "http://user:password@proxy-ip:proxy-port"; };

Acquire::https { Proxy "https://user:password@proxy-ip:proxy-port"; };
```

Comment: i have used the same syntax. any idea why i am getting below..$ wget www.google.com
--2019-07-19 01:42:02--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving <myproxy.net>.. 10.120.80.79
Connecting <myproxy.net>(myproxy.net)|10.120.80.79|:80... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2019-07-19 01:42:02 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in terminal to show the connection to NIC

step 1
    `nmcl con show` to know the nic connection

step 2
    `nmcli con up ....`  what you get in step 1

Comment: Typo in step 1 "nmcl".
Regardless, this is not  an answer to the question.  This is a proxy related question.